# hashmap.get() returning wrong values even though they are all correct in the map

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Goal is to take in a String[] length 36 and it will be a 6x6 array from 1x1 to 6x6 then print out the coordinates of a word found in the 2d array. Easy enough. I have placed each array item into the map with the corresponding coordinates (as a String value because I need to return a String). If I print all the values they print correctly 11 through 66, but if the input is "NO70JE3A4Z28X1GBQKFYLPDVWCSHUTM65R9I" for example I get "1271" as an output when I should be getting "1166". Any ideas? Here's my code.

```
     int rcounter = 1;
    int ccounter = 1;
    HashMap<String, String> soup = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (ccounter == 7) {
            ccounter = 1;
            rcounter++;}
        String row = Integer.toString(rcounter);
        String column = Integer.toString(ccounter);
        soup.put(a[i], row + column);
        ccounter++;
        if (i == 36) {
            break; }
            System.out.println(row+column); }


    return soup.get("N") + soup.get("I");
```

Comment: Show us the definition of array: `a`

Comment: a is what I used as the example: "NO70JE3A4Z28X1GBQKFYLPDVWCSHUTM65R9I"

Comment: I compile the code (although I have to use `soup.put(new String(""+a[i]), row + column);` instead of what you used), and I get `1166` (the correct answer).

Comment: "NO70JE3A4Z28X1GBQKFYLPDVWCSHUTM65R9I" is a string, not an array. You're calling it with `a[i]`. This code won't compile!

Comment: @hawks77 I think what @alsafin wanted was for you to give us the code you use to initialise the char array `a`. You may well use a method that causes a parasite char to appear before the other chars.

Comment: @alfasin I used `char a[] = "NO70JE3A4Z28X1GBQKFYLPDVWCSHUTM65R9I".toCharArray();` and I have no trouble getting the correct answer. I don't know what OP does to get his answer.

Comment: @hawks77 are you really sure that there is no duplicated keys??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin there are no duplicates in the example above.

Comment: @AntonH Char != String. Soup is defined as `HashMap<String, String>()`. Just saying... ;)

Comment: @alfasin I know, that's why I use `new String(""+a[i])` in the `put`. Check out the code in my answer, it works, and gives correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used (almost exactly copy/pasted) which gives a correct answer:

```
public class Testtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a[] = "NO70JE3A4Z28X1GBQKFYLPDVWCSHUTM65R9I".toCharArray(); // line added to have array "a"

        int rcounter = 1;
        int ccounter = 1;
        Map<String, String> soup = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (ccounter == 7) {
                ccounter = 1;
                rcounter++;}
            String row = Integer.toString(rcounter);
            String column = Integer.toString(ccounter);

            soup.put(new String(""+a[i]), row + column); // line changed to add a String, not a Char, to HashMap
            ccounter++;
            if (i == 36) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(row+column);
        }

        System.out.println("result: " + soup.get("N") + soup.get("I")); // changed to display result, rather than return it
    }
}
```

With this code, with almost no changes, and using the String you provided, I get a correct result:

```
result: 1166
```

I believe, as hinted by `@alfasin`, that the problem is in the way you're initialising your char array `a`, and that one parasite character is appearing at the first place, right at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Yeps, this workaround for the char issue does work. +1

Comment: I did have a parasite somewhere, funny this is for a code challenge for fun and the parasite existed in the Scanner they had set up for the challenge, so I never thought I would get an error from that piece of code. Glad I'm not crazy on the algorithm.