# Method put of hashMap overwrites values of already stored data

Tags: java, hashmap

I use a hashMap to store data (certificate details) which is read from a file.
The key and value is stored in the hashMap but after calling the put method, ALL values have the value of the last added entry.
I guess it is also related to
[hashmap.get() returning wrong values even though they are all correct in the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965046/hashmap-get-returning-wrong-values-even-though-they-are-all-correct-in-the-map)
but I don't see my error:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> certDataMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    String line="";
    String bankName = "", validTill = "", fingerPrint = "";
    File certDat = new File(certDataFile);
    int cntEntries=0;
    String[] data = {"dummy", "dummy"};

    if (certDat.exists()) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(certDat);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line=scanner.nextLine();
                bankName=line.split("\\|")[0];
                validTill=line.split("\\|")[1];
                fingerPrint=line.split("\\|")[2];
                logger.debug("line: {} bankName: {} validTill: {} fingerPrint: {}",line, bankName, validTill, fingerPrint);
                data[0]=validTill;
                data[1]=fingerPrint;
                certDataMap.put(bankName, data);
                debugCertMap();
                cntEntries++;
            }
            scanner.close();
            logger.debug("{} read from {}", cntEntries, certDataFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(certDataFile,e);
        }
    } else
        logger.error(certDataFile+" not found! New file will be created if certificates were downloaded");
```

The problem was the declaration of string array data outside the loop as mentioned by Jonathan:

```
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line=scanner.nextLine();
            bankName=line.split("\\|")[0];
            validTill=line.split("\\|")[1];
            fingerPrint=line.split("\\|")[2];
            logger.debug("line: {} bankName: {} validTill: {} fingerPrint: {}",line, bankName, validTill, fingerPrint);
            String[] data = {validTill, fingerPrint};
            certDataMap.put(bankName, data);
            debugCertMap();
            cntEntries++;
```

Comment: possibly this is because value is array - and you are using the same array for each value ? try to use                 `certDataMap.put(bankName, Arrays.copyOf(data))`

Comment: what if you declare your objects inside while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is actually reference and you are using the same object data for each line. Use a new object.

Comment: Strings are immutable. So `bankName` is not the problem here since it always becomes a new String. But the `data` array is always the same array. So this is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use same object `String[] data = {"dummy", "dummy"};`, where `data` is the **reference** to the array.

But look at your code. All these could be done very simply and avoid these problems.

Create data holder class, that represents single line from the file:

```
public static final class Data {

    private final String bankName;
    private final String validTill;
    private final String fingerPrint;

    public Data(String[] line) {
        bankName = line[0];
        validTill = line[1];
        fingerPrint = line[2];
    }
}
```

And provide a method that accept `Path` and retrieve file content with required format:

```
public static Map<String, Data> read(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path)
                .map(line -> new Data(line.split("\\|")))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getBankName, Function.identity()));
}
```

That's all!